# Facebook graph api returns only one item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was using facebook graph api "/me/home" for my app. But now it returns just 1 record. It happened just in 2 days. Does anyone run into the same issue? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, It would be useful if you would add a tag to your question to say the OS you are programming for. I will assume that you are having the issue with Android, like myself.

I also just recently ran into this problem at the same time as you. I hadn't reported a bug to Facebook, as I thought that maybe it's something I'm doing wrong, even though I didn't seem to change anything that would affect Facebook's operation in my code.

It seems that it started happening after the update from Graph API v2.1 to v2.2 (even though in my app, I define that I will be using v2.1). I see nothing in the API Change Log that indicates any issues (it's mostly changes to Facebook Pages, not the news feed).

Using the GraphAPI Explorer tool doesn't seem to have these issues. I have tried updating my Facebook Android SDK to 3.20.0 (the latest), and specifying my app to use Graph API v2.2 to no avail.

I was using the limit parameter in my app, and I found that limiting to a value less than 21 wouldn't return any data. Having no limit only returned a single item of data, as you have found.

I somewhat worked-around the issue by setting the limit parameter to 50. It seems that every '5' I add to the limit, I get 1 more item of data... rather odd. So using a limit of 50 returns around 12 items of data. Sometimes more, sometimes less. It's very unstable.

In case you don't know... you add parameters to your Graph API request in the Android SDK as follows:

```
// Define the GraphAPI request
Request graphRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, graphPath, new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        ...
    }

});

// Define parameters for GraphAPI request
Bundle graphParams = new Bundle();
graphParams.putInt("limit", 50); // Will return 12 items of data? Bugged!

// Set the parameters to the request
graphRequest.setParameters(graphParams);

// Execute the request
graphRequest.executeAndWait() // This is run off the UI thread.
```

Update:

A bug report has been filed and Facebook is looking into it
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/675008585946360/

Comment: Whhen im going to facebook.developers and to Graph Api Explorer, it still returns only group posts.

Comment: There is now  bug report on Facebook.  They are looking into the issue